# Tag <? Misbehaving in PHP

Tags: php

I'm working with a legacy code that someone had left, and it happens to be my task to re-deploy the code. I'm using Windows Server 2003, Apache 2.0.63 and PHP 5.2.10.

It doesn't work. At least, not in the way I had expected it to work. Call it bugs, if you will.

Upon inspecting, I had a suspicion that this code (which appears numerous times in the application) is the culprit.

```
    &$this->
```

To illustrate the problem, I reproduce this code:

```
    <?php
       phpinfo();
       //$variable = &$this->request;
    ?>
```

The code above executed beautifully and as expected. However, if I change the code to:

```
    <?
       phpinfo();
       //$variable = &$this->request;
    ?>
```

The code misbehaves, and produce this result on the screen instead, which of course, totally unwanted and unexpected.

```
    request; ?>
```

Now, the code is littered with the similar code as above, and as such, the application now produce output on the screen similar to this one:

```
    request; $user = &$this->user; // This is comment return false; ?>
```

for a code that reads as:

```
    <?
        $request = &$this->request;
        $user = &$this->user;
        // This is comment
        return false;
    ?>
```

I had tried to change every <? with <?php whenever &$this-> rears its ugly head, but most of the time, it introduces a new error instead.

I reinstalled PHP and Apache, even using another version of PHP (5.2.6) and it still won't work. I deployed the code in my localhost (Mac OS X, PHP 5.2.8 and Apache 2.0.63) and it worked without a hassle.

Please, anyone, *any* enlightenment will more than suffice.

Comment: I feel like I'm playing a "what's different" game.  What is the difference between your first two examples?

Comment: well, apparently is not a bug as I had thought it was, but rather my PHP configuration. The question has been answered and the issue has been solved.

Comment: @rpflo - in example 1 the opening tag is <?php, and example 2 it is <?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your php.ini, you need to set the following directive:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php):

> Tells whether the short form (`<? ?>`)
>   of PHP's open tag should be allowed...

If you have time on your hands, you may want to consider replacing all those short tags '`<?`' with the full-form ones `<?php`, for better portability (see what just happened to you? :)

Comment: @karim79, I had tried to do that, but most of the times, it complains about &$this not being bla...bla...bla... Plus, it's not my code, and you know how it is to work with someone else's codes.

Comment: @Rhama Arya Wibawa - can you please paste the error in your question or here

Comment: @karim79 well, the error was recorded in the Apache's error_log (it's not there anymore as I had deleted the previous Apache's installation folders) and now that it has been fixed, albeit using method that isn't really recommended, I'm not eager to reproduce the error. :(

Comment: @Rhama Arya Wibawa - it's not a big deal, the important thing is you got it working :) I just mentioned that for information purposes, I wasn't trying to make you feel bad.

Answer (score 2):

my recommendation is not to use open tags, because it can interfere with `<?xml` codes.
I also had that problem before, just go and replace all `<?php` to `<?` , and then again all `<?`  to `<?php`.

In this way you won't get any

```
<?  <-- one space after the '?'
```

and

```
<?php  <-- one space after the 'p'
```

hope this will help...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the short tags:
`("<?")`

they need to be enabled in you php.ini.  See this [link.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)