# shorter way of echoing a variable in php?

Tags: php

In the last two days, ive run across code that has php echo'd variables displayed like this

```
<?=$selected?>
```

What exactly is going on and why? What is this called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's called a Short Tag. It's a shortcut to `<?php echo $selected;?>`. It is widely adopted, but there's a lot of literature out there that does not recommend its use as it leads to less portable code (many PHP installations do not have short tags enabled). I happen to agree, just take a look at [this user's woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275718/tag-misbehaving-in-php/). Also, see:

[Are PHP Short Tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: but remember, short tags are deprecated in PHP 6. You can enable short tags by using ini_set()

Comment: You can't enable it with ini_set(), because the file is parsed before any ini_set() are executed, and at the time they are executed, the PHP document has been parsed already. If you want to use <?= and still have portable application, you can use a stream wrapper that converts short tags to long tags. This is what Zend Framework does for example (eg. include 'zend.view://file.php'), but be aware that it degrades performance.