# <?= ?> special tags in php

Tags: php, php-shorttags

can anybody please explain what are these special tags in php?

```
<?= ?>
```

I couldn't find it on google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656795/shorter-way-of-echoing-a-variable-in-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [short_open_tags](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag) setting.
`<?=` is identical to `<? echo` and use of it requires `short_open_tag` to be on. A term to search for would be "short tags".

As an example: `<?='hello'?>` is identical to `<? echo 'hello' ?>` which is a short form of `<?php echo 'hello' ?>`.

See also [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use) here on SO.

Comment: Thanks salathe for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @heapzero: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413661/php6-is-short-open-tag-removed-or-deprecated-or-neither/2413675#2413675

Comment: @Alix Axel
Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4):

It's part of the [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php). Basically `<?=$foo?>` is equivalent to `<?php echo $foo; ?>`

Comment: Short_open_tag is primary <? ?>. "Short_open_tag also affects the shorthand <?=, which is identical to <? echo. Use of this shortcut requires short_open_tag to be on" - citation from php.net. So it is not basically short_open_tag.

Comment: Indeed retro, I modified my answer to be more specific :)

Answer (score 1):

They output what's inside them directly.

```
<?= "something" ?>
```

is a shortcut for:

```
<?php echo "something"; ?>
```

These (together with `<? ?>`) are called short tags. [See here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) (short_open_tag)

Answer (score 0):

`<?= $foobar ?>` is a shortcut for `<?php echo $foobar; ?>`.

I wouldn't recommend using these short tags because in some webserver environments they are disabled via PHPs configuration.

Comment: Any decent PHP application requires a lot of configuration options, from mod_rewrite to memory_limit and post_max_size. Go tell everyone these are not recommended for use

Answer (score 0):

yes you can done it using .htaccess. In your .htaccess file, add this

```
php_value short_open_tag 1
```

Now you can check files with `<?='hi';?>` instead of `<?php ?>`