# What is the PHP syntax "<?="

Tags: php, tags

Reading some PHP code and I cannot understand the usage of:

`<?=`

I understand the php tag use of:

`<?php` and `<?`

The exact usage I am reading is:

`<?=$form->hidden('mode',$mode); ?>`

where $form is a new instantiated class of an object and "hidden" a class method.  All of that is understood, but when I place even a space between the ? and = of `<?=` I get an error of:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/...
```

I cannot find anything on google or php.net regarding the syntax.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [<?= ?> special tags in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662476/special-tags-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?=` is shorthand for `<?php echo`. Its usage isn't recommended any more, apparently because of some ambiguity with the parser or incompatibility with some PHP versions, though I still see it in big projects like Drupal.

Edit: They're called "short tags" and a discussion on whether they should be used or not can be found here: [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  In it they discuss the <?= as supported by Zend.  It had a lot of links and thoughts on the subject, along with the php.net manual links posted on here.  Thank you to all.

Answer (score 2):

It's a shortcut for `echo`. Something like this (where `expr` is any expression):

```
<?= expr ?>
```

is functionally equivalent to this:

```
<?php echo expr; ?>
```

It's not recommended to use this syntax as it's not enabled on some servers. (and if someone is using shared hosting, they may not be able to re-enable it, either)

The PHP documentation on it is [here](http://www.php.net/language.basic-syntax.phpmode#example-65).

Answer (score 1):

It is called the [short open tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). If it is enabled on your server, then you may use it.

**From PHP Manual:**

> This directive also affected the shorthand `<?=` before PHP 5.4.0, which
>   is identical to `<? echo`. Use of this shortcut required short_open_tag
>   to be on. Since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available.

The use of these type of tags allow you to receive the same result as using `echo`. The following examples are equivalent.

**Example:**

```
<?php echo $text; ?>
<?= $text; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

"Short open tags" are hell, in short. If you have short_open_tags on in your php.ini / httpd.conf / .htaccess and you try to put an XML tag into your document, like so...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

PHP will think you tried to write some PHP, error, and die. You end up having to do

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<?=`, when `short_tags` is enabled, is a shorthand for `<?php echo`.

This is covered [right at the start of the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Just a shorthand to quickly print content when, for example, you are in an HTML file. Its usage is not recommended since it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

<?=stuff here;?> is a shorthand of <?php echo stuff here;?>

http://mattsblog.ca/2007/07/26/tip-of-the-day-php-shorthand/

Answer (score 0):

That is a short tag and is not available for use on all servers.

`<?=` is the same as `<?php echo`

Putting a space in `<?=` invalidates the short tag which is why you get your error.