# What's the difference between <?php ?> and <? ?>

Tags: php, syntax, tags

I can't find the answer anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: What about the manual?

Comment: possible duplicate of [shorter way of echoing a variable in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656795/shorter-way-of-echoing-a-variable-in-php)

Comment: Well said Bolt.. (+1) what is the difference between <?PHP ?> and <?php ?> :)

Comment: Bolt - Although I see your point, keep in mind this *is* a Q&A site. And this is actually a great title for the question - it will be much easier for someone to find than the dupe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically,

`<? ?>` are short tags. However, not every php installation has short tags enabled. Therefore, even though  is faster to type than the normal tags (`<?php ?>`), it may not work if you move your code to another server.

[Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

EDIT:
Also, if you're using xml in your web page, you might run into conflicts, as writing `<?xml version="1.0"?>` will make you run into a PHP error, as xml version="1.0" isn't PHP!

If you're using XML and PHP you may need to `<?php echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\""; ?>`

Comment: Shouldn't php react only to `<?_..._?>` (where '_' means *space*)?

Comment: @BlaXpirit Not at all. I just wrote a sample script, with "<?xml version="1.0"?>" as the code, and I got the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: Anyways, it's best to simply disable `short_open_tags` in php.ini, as I mentoined in my post.

Answer (score 3):

In your php.ini, if you want `<?` and `?>` to work, you need to turn on 
"short tags". 
However, it is better to write long-tag compliant code in the first place.

Acutally is no difference.

Answer (score 2):

They both mean the same, with the difference that the short form `<? ?>` is not always supported/enabled.

Answer (score 2):

There acutally is no difference between the two, the second one is bascially just a shorthand. I personally would recommend using the longer version, because on some systems, the second possibilty is disabled in the `php.ini` (see `short_open_tags`).

Answer (score 2):

It is always better to use `<?php ?>` as on some installations of php `<? ?>` is not supported! If this happens your code will not work!